# "an adapter was given to :pubsub but no :name was defined" with Elixir/Phoenix after v0.9.0

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This error comes up when running `mix compile` after switching to Phoenix master after starting with v0.9.0:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/youli/endpoint.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) an adapter was given to :pubsub but no :name was defined, please pass the :name option accordingly
    lib/youli/endpoint.ex:2: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:657: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

I haven't changed anything in this file, and it doesn't look like the template for it has changed either.

```
diff lib/youli/endpoint.Ex \
    <(cat deps/phoenix/priv/template/lib/application_name/endpoint.ex \
    | sed 's/<%= application_name %>/youli/g' \
    | sed 's/<%= application_module %>/Youli/g')
=> nothing important
```

Any hint as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a `:name` in your options now. `pubsub: [name: MyApp.PubSub, adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]`

Comment: I see, the change goes in config/config.exs.